# Number of line in website

Tags: web-access

I want to download the content of the website(contains text) and only a few lines from the content (from a specific number of the line up to the last line minus specific offset). Unfortunately, I do not know how to get the number of line in the content. For example, I want to replace 59 with the length of the content minus specific offset.

```
data1 = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree"];
Snippet[data1, 51 ;; 59]
```

Comment: You mean from line 51 to the end? `Snippet[data1, 51 ;;]`.

Comment: @corey979 I edit the question to be more specific

Comment: `Snippet[data1, 51 ;; -17]`

Comment: @corey979 thank you for the answer,but if I'm interested to know the length of the content. How I can get it?

Comment: So you want to know the length of the content, not take its snippet from a given line to the end, or to some numbered line from the end? So that's quite different than you have in the question: "_replace 59 with the length of the content minus specific offset_" would give the same outputs as my codes above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to split the imported data on newlines using `StringSplit` so the length of the resulting list is the line count. Then we can use `Riffle` and `StringJoin` to get the selected lines:

```
Module[{start = 51, offset = 85, raw, data, linecount, stop},
 raw = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree"];
 data = StringTrim@StringSplit[raw, "\n"];
 linecount = Length@data;
 stop = linecount - offset;
 Print["# lines: ", linecount];
 Print["  start: ", start];
 Print["   stop: ", stop];
 Print["# saved: ", stop - start];
 data = Take[data, {start, stop}];
 Riffle[data, " "] // StringJoin]
```

Alternatively, we could count newlines in the raw data and use `Snippet` as corey979 points out in the comments:

```
 Module[{start = 51, offset = 85, raw, linecount, stop, counter = 0},
 raw = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree"];
 linecount = Block[{str = StringToStream[raw]},
   While[Read[str, Record, NullRecords -> True] =!= EndOfFile, 
    counter++];
   Close[str]; counter];
 stop = linecount - offset;
 Print["# lines: ", linecount];
 Print["  start: ", start];
 Print["   stop: ", stop];
 Print["# saved: ", stop - start];
 Snippet[raw, start ;; stop]]
```

The result for the website specified in the question gives:

> This section describes the query operation of a segment tree in a \
>   one-dimensional space. A query for a segment tree, receives a point q
>   \ x (should be one of the leaves of tree), and retrieves a list of all
>   \ the segments stored which contain the point q x . Formally stated; \
>   given a node (subtree) v and a query point q x , the query can be \
>   done using the following algorithm: Report all the intervals in I ( v
>   \ ). If v is not a leaf: If q x is in Int(left child of v ) then

Answer (score 5):

```
length = ToExpression[ToString[StringCount[#,"\n"] & /@ FullForm[data1]]]+1
Snippet[data1,138;;length]
```

> This page was last edited on 27 January 2019, at 05:26 (UTC) . Text \
>   is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike \
>   License ; additional terms may apply. By using this site, you agree \
>   to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy . Wikipedia® is a registered \
>   trademark of the Wikimedia Foundation, Inc. , a non-profit \
>   organization.
>   Privacy policy About Wikipedia Disclaimers Contact Wikipedia \
>   Developers Cookie statement Mobile view